# Join rows without losing column data

Tags: sql

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
ID  Bool1  Bool2  Bool3
A     0      0      1
A     1      0      0
A     0      1      0
A     0      0      1
B     1      0      0
B     0      1      0
```

And I want to convert it into

```
ID  Bool1  Bool2  Bool3
A     1      1      1
B     1      1      0
```

Meaning to have only a **distinct ID** and each **distinct ID** will receive all the "1" values it given.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `max()` aggregation and `group by`

```
select id, max(bool1) as bool1, max(bool2) as bool2,max(bool3) as bool3
from tablename
group by id
```